# In Bigquery Join two tables append all existing values table1 from table2 and where no intersection leave null

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

Hello stackoverflow community! May I ask to help with query in bigquery

I have table1 which contains user_id and their data

| user_id | age | order_name | details | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | t-shir | item1 | new |
| 2 | 22 | skirt | item2 | new |
| 3 | 48 | puffer | item3 | old |
| 4 | 19 | ball | item5 | old |
| 5 | 56 | rocket | item4 | new |

And table 2 which contains user_id and user_name (but it contains only specific users)

| user_id | user_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 3 | Bob |
| 4 | Kyle |

How can i get such result in output in bigquery:

| user_id | age | order_name | details | type | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | t-shir | item1 | new | John |
| 2 | 22 | skirt | item2 | new | null |
| 3 | 48 | puffer | item3 | old | Bob |
| 4 | 19 | ball | item5 | old | Kyle |
| 5 | 56 | rocket | item4 | new | null |

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you tag a bigquery question with mysql, if mysql is a completely different database product?

Comment: @Shadow i understand it, but tag also mysql, because it have similar approach. Maybe you can help me with my questions?

Comment: This could potentially be true to any other random database product that uses some form of SQL. The emphasis is on the word similar, but not the same! Please don't do this in the future! Btw, check out left joins...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t.user_id= t2.user_id
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/35344556)